# Lose data in random fields when importing from file into table using phpmyadmin

Tags: ms-access, random, import, phpmyadmin, null

I have an access DB. I exported tables to xlsx. Then I saved as .ods using openOffice
because I found out that phpmyadmin-mysql no longer supports excel files. I have my mySQL database formated exactly as it should to accept the data. I import and everything seems fine except one little detail.

In some fields, the value is NULL instead of the value it should have according to the .ods file. Some rows show the same value for that field correctly, some show NULL.

Also, the "faulty" rows have some fields that show the value 0 for fields that where empty in the imported file (instead of NULL). Default value for those fields in mySQL is NULL. Each row has many fields like that and all of the same data type (tinyint). Some appear correctly NULL and some have the value 0....

I can't see a pattern on all these.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I managed to import via .csv but that is not a solution since csv empty fields are entered as 0s and not as NULL in my new db.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that imported strings have ("") quotes and NULL do not and that all are separated appropriately, usually a "," comma with the record/row delimited by ";" semicolon. Best way to check what the MySQL is looking for is to export some existing data to the same format and check it against what you are trying to import. One little missed quote and the deal is off. Be consistent in the use of either  double " quotes or single ' quotes. also the ` character is not used as I think. If you are "squishing" your data through an application that applies "smart quotes" like MS word does or "Open Office??' this too can cause issues. Add the word NULL either inside or without quotes in your csv import where values appropriate.